# Deploy vaadin app to Google App Engine - Error NOT_FOUND

Tags: google-app-engine, vaadin, web.xml

I successfully deployed a Vaadin application, but when calling it I see `ERROR : NOT_FOUND` 
I suppose that my default page is not found,because the default page is selected wrong.

**Question:**
How can I point (I suppose in my web.xml) to my default page?

My `web.xml`

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
              <display-name>GoogleAppVaadin701Project</display-name>
              <welcome-file-list>
                <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
                <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
              </welcome-file-list>
            </web-app>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin eclipse plugin does not create web.xml which works for vaadin application. In the book of vaadin you can find section about web.xml - https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/application.environment.html

following is basic servlet definition and mapping based on the book which works fine. Just change the UI parameter to point to your UI implementation

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
    com.vaadin.server.GAEVaadinServlet
  </servlet-class>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>UI</param-name>
    <param-value>com.example.higoogle.HigoogleUI</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```